# Does Grand Maester Pycelle have an agenda?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* series the character Grand Maester Pycelle seems perfectly content to brew potions, give bad advice and hit on handmaidens. I'm not saying that he doesn't serve a purpose, he has done a lot to support house Lannister. But does he actually want anything? Is he actually trying to get somewhere or achieve something?
I'm not asking for spoilers I'm just asking if I've missed something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pycelle has an intense desire to maintain the status quo of his own position and as such, will do everything within his power to support those who will allow him to maintain his capacity. Those who can or will not accommodate this will be on his bad side, thus he will work against them via the manipulation of his feeble old man ruse. This explains his intense support of Joffrey and disdain for Tyrion and Qyburn.

Comment: [This deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMXJlUIQP94) provides some interesting information about Pycelle.